# How to load css files in codeigniter?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

How can I load the css file in views/css/stylesheet.css in CI? My index file is in views/firstView.php

I am completely new to code igniter. Thought editing the config.php like this would work:

`$config['index_page'] = 'localhost/Projects/first_CI/application/views/firstView.php';`

but its not working :( . Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 2):

put a css folder in your root directory and inside the folder put your css files.

now in firstView.php filr include the css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css" title="" charset="utf-8">  //if your css file is style.css otherwise change style.css with yours
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to watch some youtube videos on codeigniter
   .Css files are not added like that 
   You have to set asset_url() function ,create folder assets in application directory and put css in that folder and include it ,
thats the recdomended method

Answer (score 0):

If your style.css is placed under the `static` directory which is located in your website root directory, you can refer it by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/signup.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()."css/style.css";?>">
```

Create css folder at the root and put css file in that folder.